# Mysterious error when accessing BRENDA with zeep

Tags: zeep

I'm trying to get all human Kcats and KMs from BRENDA using SOAP (technically zeep with Python3 I guess). I used this code, which follows the example code given [here](https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap.php):

```
from zeep import Client
import hashlib

wsdl = "https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap/brenda_zeep.wsdl"
password = hashlib.sha256("password".encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
client = Client(wsdl)
parameters = (
    "email@email.com",
    password,
    "organism*Homo sapiens"
)
resultString = client.service.getKcatKmValue(*parameters)
```

and it gives me the error "Missing element organism (getKcatKmValue.organism)"

It's not clear to me what I'm doing wrong. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: If my answer does help then please mark it as accepted otherwise let us know the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run this command to inspect the definition of methods/operations:
`python -mzeep https://www.brenda-enzymes.org/soap/brenda_zeep.wsdl`

you can see the definition of `getKcatKmValue` as follows:

```
getKcatKmValue(email: xsd:string, password: xsd:string, ecNumber: xsd:string, organism: xsd:string, kcatKmValue: xsd:string, kcatKmValueMaximum: xsd:string, substrate: xsd:string, commentary: xsd:string, ligandStructureId: xsd:string, literature: xsd:string) -> return: ns0:ArrayOfKcatKmValues
```

so all of these parameters must be supplied which you are not passing in `parameters` hence the error.

a `dict` can also be passed to operation for a better visibility of passed arguments like this:

```
parameters = {
    'email': "email@email.com",
    'password': password,
    'ecNumber': ecNumber,
    'organism': "organism*Homo sapiens",
    'kcatKmValue': kcatKmValue,
    'kcatKmValueMaximum': kcatKmValueMaximum,
    'substrate': substrate,
    'commentary': commentary,
    'ligandStructureId': ligandStructureId,
    'literature' : literature
}

# then pass dict as follows:
resultString = client.service.getKcatKmValue(**parameters)
```

hope this helps.